# select2 change dropdown values on selected

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-select2

I've made an API who makes search. The response of the api is always a json file. The response contains some aggregations of the results too.
For the frontend part I've made a search select bar with Select2.js.
I want to change the values of dropdown (and automatically display them) when the user select an aggregation.
The steps are thease:

1. User: type something on the select bar
2. Api: search what the user wrote
3. Select2: display results
4. User: select an aggregation
5. Api: makes a group by the aggregation selected
6. Select2: display new results

this is my js code, the queries works, but select2 not diplay new values

```
$('.SearchQueryBox').select2({
    tags: true,
    placeholder: 'search something',
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: function (term) {
            return '/inspiring_indexes/search/?term=' + term;
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 50,
        cache : true,
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        }
    }
});

$('.SearchQueryBox').on('select2:select', function (e) {

    var input = e.params.data;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/inspiring_indexes/search/",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: input
    }).then(function (output) {
        console.log(output);
        // manually trigger the `select2:select` event
        $('.SearchQueryBox').trigger({
            processResults: function (output) {
                return {
                    results: output
                };
            }
        });
    });
});
```